# Need some help on the following python script

Tags: python-3.x

this is the following question and the script - 
**The counter function counts down from start to stop when start is bigger than stop, and counts up from start to stop otherwise. Fill in the blanks to make this work correctly.**

Python Script -

```py
def counter(start, stop):
    x = start
    if ___:
        return_string = "Counting down: "
        while x >= stop:
            return_string += str(x)
            if ___:
                return_string += ","
            ___
    else:
        return_string = "Counting up: "
        while x <= stop:
            return_string += str(x)
            if ___:
                return_string += ","
            ___
    return return_string

    print(counter(1, 10)) # Should be "Counting up: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"
    print(counter(2, 1)) # Should be "Counting down: 2,1"
    print(counter(5, 5)) # Should be "Counting up: 5"
```

Comment: This is not a place for doing homeworks.

Comment: Rather than a while loop, you could let python handle the counting using `range`. You could subtract start from stop and see if the result is more than or equal to 0, in which case the step is 1, else the step is -1.

Comment: @EdWard We think he is doing homework here, so his teacher gave him that and he just has to complete the spaces.

Comment: Sorry I misread the code... I guess it wasn't properly formatted when I first saw it :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like homework but anyways,

```
def counter(start, stop): 
x = start 
if x>stop:
    return_string = "Counting down: " 
    while x >= stop:
        return_string += str(x) 
        if x>stop: 
            return_string += "," 
        x = x - 1
else: 
    return_string = "Counting up: " 
    while x <= stop: 
        return_string += str(x) 
        if x<stop: 
            return_string += "," 
        x = x + 1
return return_string
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def counter(start, stop):
x = start
if start > stop:
    return_string = "Counting down: "
    while x >= stop:
        return_string += str(x)
        x -= 1
        if start != stop:
            return_string += ","
else:
    return_string = "Counting up: "
    while x <= stop:
        return_string += str(x)
        x += 1
        if start != stop:
            return_string += ","
return return_string.strip(",")
```